Installing SAGA plugin on a Mac
I am currently trying to use the Kriging tool on SAGA in order to show the daily precipitation data I have gathered over the course of a few years. However, when I set my points and attribute column in the parameters for this to happen, and I run the tool to interpolate the data it says: "Problem with the SAGA installation: Unsupported SAGA version (found 7.8.2, required >=9.1", which is confusing since when I installed the plugin, underneath the name of the plugin itself it says: "A Processing provider for SAGA 9.1", does this not mean that I downloaded the 9.1 version. I am currently using the QGIS 3.34 Prizren to do this (if that makes a difference), I'm kinda new to using QGIS.
